# Handling Promise based exceptions: foreach vs for.. of

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise

I have a requirement to execute a NodeJs method as shown below (Syntax in TypeScript). The child function checkEntityForPromotion is invoked by the parent function triggerPromotion as shown below.

```
  async triggerPromotion(fileNames: string[],
  ): Promise<string> {
    var entityList = await this.listEntity();
    fileNames.forEach(async fileName => {
      var matchingEntity = entityList.entities.filter(rec => rec.ref.replaceAll("\\","/").includes(fileName))[0]
      if (matchingEntity != null) {
        await this.checkEntityForPromotion(matchingEntity)
      }

    })
    return Promise.reject(
      new BizError({
        message: BizErrorTips.PROMOTION_FAILED,
        description: 'detail description in here.',
      }),
    ); 
  }
```

```
async checkEntityForPromotion(entity: Entity, ): Promise<Boolean> {
    var versionToBePromoted = entity.version
    var existingVersion = await ValidateReqUtil.getAzureStreamingVersion(entity.name)
    //If the version to be promoted does not match the version in lower environment, do not proceed further.  
    if (versionToBePromoted != existingVersion) {
        return Promise.reject(`Entity version to be promoted ${versionToBePromoted} is not the same as existing entity version ${existingVersion}`)
    }
    return Promise.resolve(true) 
  }
```

The above invocation from the forEach loop returns the following error, when the child process throws an exception.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "Entity version to be promoted 1.0.2 is not the same as existing entity version 1.0.1".
```

However if I replace the forEach with a for.. of loop like below, I get the correct exception behavior, where the catch block gets activated as expected.

```
for (const fileName of fileNames){}
```

Is there any suggestion on why the two for loop constructs behave in a different way? I am guessing an additional catch block is needed for the foreach, because of an inline function, but wanted to understand the underlyign rationale.

Thanks a lot for your time.
Prabal

Comment: It's basically just that `.forEach` doesn't know anything about promises. It's designed to synchronously loop through an array, calling the function for each element. `.forEach` completely ignores the return value from the function, so if the function returns a promise, it pays no attention and moves on.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NicholasTower It helps, as I was not familiar with the difference

Comment: You should use `map` or `reduce` to build up some promises instead of using `forEach` because the your callback returns a promise and you need to capture that so you can await it.